# Javascript: why to declare the same value of the same variable twice?

Tags: javascript, function, while-loop

I want a prompt appear and ask user to type in a correct password. And every time user types in the wrong pw, the prompt should re-appear. I don't understand why the following code wouldn't work:

```
var secret = prompt("What is the password?");
while ( secret !== "sesame" ) {
 secret;    
}
document.write("Welcome.");
```

If `"secret"` is a global variable then inside the while loop it should be interpreted as having the value of `prompt("What is the password?")`?

But it turns out that I should write `secret = prompt("What is the password?");`inside the while loop:

```
var secret = prompt("What is the password?");
    while ( secret !== "sesame" ) {
     secret = prompt("What is the password?");    
    }
    document.write("Welcome.");
```

Why to declare the same value of variable `secret` twice?

Comment: `prompt()` is a function, but not a value

Comment: well, i'm not sure what you expect the `secret` inside the `while` loop to do on in the first example, because it isn't doing anything

Comment: You know that JS passwords are useless, right?

Comment: What are all the down votes for? He asked a valid question. just because he's a noob developer, doesn't mean he should get down voted.

Comment: @AndrewL. Read what? If everyone would have read what they needed to know before asking, SO wouldn't be needed

Answer (score 2):

A line of code that is simply `secret;` does nothing - it merely references, but does nothing with, a variable named `secret`.

What you mean to do is:

```
var secret;
while(secret !== 'secretpassword') secret = prompt("What's the password?");
```

For the first iteration of the loop `secret` does not equal the secret password, so the prompt is run. And it will run repeatedly until the correct one is entered.

However, there's a lot of problems with your approach.

Firstly, ever-lasting dialog windows (of which a prompt is a kind) are not very UI friendly; they necessarily demand focus so you can't click away from them without interacting with them. What if the user wanted to dismiss the prompt and click a "forgot pass" link or use some other part of the page?

Secondly, storing a password in JavaScript is a massive and obvious security risk, but I'll assume this is a tutorial or homework of some kind where the focus is not on security.

Thirdly, `document.write()` is long-ago deprecated and there's almost no use for it these days. Look instead into DOM-scripting.

Answer (score 0):

When you assign an expression in a variable, the variable only contains the value returned by that expression, not the expression itself

Therefore, evaluating the variable won't have any effect, and won't evaluate the assigned expression again.

If you don't want to repeat the function call, you can use a `do while` loop

```
var secret;
do {
  secret = prompt("What is the password?");
} while ( secret !== "sesame" );
```

But of course, JS passwords are useless